# Ajax submission based on a mapped array

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Im having an array

```
array(0=>12,1=>16,3=>20,4=>25);
```

And i have two buttons in my page

```
<button id="next">Next</button>
<button id="prev">Previous</button>
```

On a page load an ajax call will go with `data` 12 (first element of the array) and it fetches results for me..working fine

My issue is when i click the next button i need to pass 16 to the ajax call..(because 12 is the last submitted value) and again click next i need to pass 20 to the ajax

and if i click prev i need to pass 16 because 20 is the current value

So how do i know which element to pass to the ajax

heres my ajax

```
 $.ajax({
            url : baseurl+'/ajax/warehousedetails',
            type:"post",
            data:{"crid":<<<here i want to change>>>>},         
            success:function(data){
                console.log(data);


            }
        });
```

Thank you

Comment: Any sample of your code?

Comment: Take a global variable `var counter=0;` which is the index of the array. now in ajax call, increase or decrease the counter according to your ajax call and send the array[counter] as data in that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the index of current element in a variable.

For example at a first time

```
Var flag = 0
```

So when you send a request first time use value

```
array[flag]
```

On the click of next

```
flag++
array[flag]
```

On the click of previous

```
flag--
array[flag]
```

Comment: I was looking for a better solution,i got it though..anyway thanks :)